# Vim: cannot see :echomsg messages in message history list

Tags: vim

I'm working on a vim script and want to see the value of a variable that is generated in the script for debugging purposes.

I use something like:

```
echomsg 'My variable = ' . b:variable
```

reload the source with

```
:source %
```

and then look the message history list with

```
:messages
```

But there's nothing there and I'm pretty sure that the command would be executed.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
I'm trying to make a change to vim-cucumber and so I wanted to see the value of a variable. In the ftplugin/cucumber.vim file, I have the following:

```
let b:cucumber_root = expand('%:p:h:s?.*[\/]\%(features\|stories\)/step_definitions/mobile_website\zs[\/].*??')
echomsg 'cucumber_root = ' . b:cucumber_root
```

Comment: Can you post the actual thing you are working on? This works for me if the `echomsg` is the only thing in the file.

Comment: do you have error message? if b:variable not exist, this expression will emit error.

Comment: No; no error message; code fragment added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the top of file you will find

```
if (exists("b:did_ftplugin"))
  finish
endif
```

Which stops the file from being sourced again after the first time. You need to `unlet b:did_ftplugin` before sourcing the file again.

Other options would be to use another tpope plugin to do this for you called [scripttease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) with the `:Runtime` command.

Comment: Excellent! i should have realized that and I will check out his stripttease plugin.